# SSH password change automation over a list of IPs

Tags: shell, for-loop, while-loop, expect

I have a bunch of linux servers. What I am trying to do is making sure all the servers have the password I want by prompting all the logins change. I am trying to implement it by writing a short bash script which includes the expect command. I am running it over a file which contains the list of IPs.

My file `ips.txt` contains:

```
10.195.166.52
10.195.166.54
```

My "expect" script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

log_file myfile.log ;# <<< === append output to a file

set timeout 180
set username pippo
set old_password 0ldp455w0rd
set new_password n3wp455w0rd
set filedes [open "ips.txt" r]
gets $filedes ip

while {$ip != -1} {
spawn ssh $username@$ip
expect "$username"
send "$old_password\r"
expect "(current)"
send "$old_password\r"
expect "New"
send "$new_password\r"
expect "Retype"
send "$new_password\r"
expect "$username"
send "exit\r"
#expect eof ;#wait for the connection to close
}
close $filedes
```

What I obtain is:

```
You are required to change your password immediately (root enforced)
Last login: Thu Jul 19 16:14:46 2018 from 10.222.233.139
WARNING: Your password has expired.
You must change your password now and login again!
Changing password for user pippo.
Changing password for pippo.
(current) UNIX password: 
New password: 
Retype new password: 
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
Connection to 10.195.166.52 closed.
send: spawn id exp6 not open
    while executing
"send "exit\r""
    ("while" body line 12)
    invoked from within
"while {$ip != -1} {
spawn ssh $username@$ip
expect "$username"
send "$old_password\r"
expect "(current)"
send "$old_password\r"
expect "New"
send "$ne..."
    (file "./passwd.xp" line 12)
```

So the script is not proceeding further than the first IP. What is happening ? I am trying variations of the expect commands without success.

Comment: don't you need `gets $filedes ip` (or similar, not an expect user) at the bottom of the `while` loop? Good luck.

Comment: Solved! The issue was in the last expect not happening. Thank you for helping!

Comment: `sexpect`. Nice! @pynexj Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Thanks for sharing